# Can we display duplicate items in an array with ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with repeated items.I want to go through all the items in my array with ng-repeat.but Iam unable to display the duplicate items which are repeated values in my array.how can i display the duplicate items with ng-repeat?

Comment: The solution probably involves a `track by` expression but without any code at all to work with, this question is impossible to answer with any confidence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs ng-repeat array - duplicate values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653811/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-duplicate-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `track by $index` after your `ng-repeat`

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

I'll be able to provide more isight if you add code to OP.